# ElasticSearch - find all documents whose nested documents do not intersect with date range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index called `employees` with a nested collection of date time ranges called `shifts`. I need to find all users who are available between a specific input date time range (i.e. input date range does not intersect with any shifts). How can I do this with ElasticSearch? This is what my index looks like (trimmed down for brevity), not sure if this is right:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "employee": {
            "properties": {
                "email": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "shifts": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "shift": {
                            "type": "date_range"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) datatype as you've mentioned, you would need to make use of [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_using_literal_nested_literal_fields_for_arrays_of_objects)

Note that I've made use of simple `yyyy-MM-dd` format for the `shifts.shift` in the mapping as shown below. I've also included sample documents, the query and response.

Do note the two scenarios/queries I've mentioned so that you are clear with what fits best for your use case.

### Mapping

```
PUT someindex
{
    "mappings": {
        "employee": {
            "properties": {
                "email": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "shifts": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "shift": {
                            "type": "date_range",
                            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST someindex/employee/1
{
  "email": "john@abc.com",
  "shifts": [
    {
      "shift": {
        "gte": "2019-01-01",
        "lte": "2019-01-03"
      }
    }
  ]
}

POST someindex/employee/2
{
  "email": "jane@abc.com",
  "shifts": [
    {
      "shift": {
        "gte": "2019-01-04",
        "lte": "2019-01-07"
      }
    }
  ]
}

POST someindex/employee/3
{
  "email": "jack@abc.com",
  "shifts": [
    {
      "shift": {
        "gte": "2019-01-08",
        "lte": "2019-01-10"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Query

**SCENARIO 1:** List of users who are available at particular range for e.g. from `2019-01-01` to `2019-01-04`. Also note the use of `nested` keyword in below query

```
POST someindex/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"shifts",
                  "query":{  
                     "range":{  
                        "shifts.shift":{  
                           "gte":"2019-01-01",
                           "lte":"2019-01-04",
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

### Response

Looking at the sample documents, you can see that the result returned both `John` and `Jane`. Note that you'd get both of them because by default the range would be `intersection`

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "employee",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "email" : "jane@abc.com",
          "shifts" : [
            {
              "shift" : {
                "gte" : "2019-01-04",
                "lte" : "2019-01-07"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "employee",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "email" : "john@abc.com",
          "shifts" : [
            {
              "shift" : {
                "gte" : "2019-01-01",
                "lte" : "2019-01-03"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**SCENARIO 2:** Now if you want to know a list of users who are available at that **exact particular time frame**, then range query would allow a field called `relation` where you can mention `contains` which would only give you the possible candidates available in that particular time range.

> Range queries over range fields support a relation parameter which can
>   be one of WITHIN, CONTAINS, INTERSECTS (default).

```
POST someindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "shifts",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "shifts.shift": {
                  "gte": "2019-01-01",
                  "lte": "2019-01-03",
                  "relation": "contains"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This is very helpful and almost perfect! I just need to find the opposite of scenario 1, basically, or all users whose existing shifts don't conflict with a new shift date range.

Comment: I was able to get the behavior I desired by using `must_not` in place of `must`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you and even more so that you figured the `must_not` part. Thank you.